# Look for a remote access software which is possible to connect even when the monitor of the host machine is not connected

Tags: remote-access, teamviewer

My setup is as follows:

- Computer 1 and Computer 2 are connecting to only 1 monitor through a HDMI Bi-Direction Switch.  Just by pressing button on HDMI Bi-Direction Switch, I  can switch between Computer  1 and Computer 2
- I have Computer 3, which wants to remote access to Computer 1.

I want to use Computer 2, and let other (Computer 3) to access Computer 1 at the same time. But I  can not  because

- When both Computer  1  and Computer 2 is turned on, but Computer 2 is using monitor.
- Then Computer 3 can not access Computer 1  anymore (in fact, Computer 3 can access,  but  can not control anything of Computer  1).  If I switch monitor to use Computer 1,  then   Computer 3 can access Computer  1 as normal.

I have tried  several software such as TeamViewer, Chrome Remote Desktop, but  none of them worked.

Can you suggest any software or any other method that works?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If the machine that you're trying to access is is running Linux, you could use ThinLinc for this task. ThinLinc will create a full virtual desktop session for the client and doesn't need a screen connected to the host machine.

ThinLinc is free for up to 5 simultaneously connected users.

Other option includes VNC (TigerVNC, etc), but I think that ThinLinc is way better and easier to setup than VNC, for example, ThinLinc already has sound redirection by default and can be accessed from multiple users simultaneously.

Comment: thanks very much. Do you know any solution for Windows?

Comment: If you're running the "Pro" version of WIndows, have you tried the embeded Remote Access tool (RDP) from Microsoft? I don't remember if it needs a locally attached monitor...
Either way, if you're running a remote desktop software that needs a locally attached screen, maybe you can workaround it by using a "Dummy Plug", which is a small connector that you plug to your video output and it will pretend that there is a monitor attached to it.